# Replacing elements in lists of a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have the following nested list

```
CombiningCyclesCase2={{1, 2, 3, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 4, 3, 0}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 3}, {3, 2, 1, 4, 0}, {3, 2, 1, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 4, 1, 5}, {3, 4, 1, 2, 5}, {3, 2, 4, 5, 1}, {3, 5, 4, 1, 2}}
```

I want to replace the zeroes in the sublists that have zeroes, by the corresponding position of the zeroes. For instance, in the sublist `{1,2,3,0,0}` I want to replace the 0's to have `{1,2,3,4,5}`, but in the sublists that don't have any zeros, I want to leave them like they are. I tried doing this with the following line of code, where n=5:

```
n = 5;
Table[If[Max[CombiningCyclesCase2[[i]]] == n, 
  CombiningCyclesCase2[[i]]], 
 ReplacePart[CombiningCyclesCase2[[i]], 
  Thread[Range[Max[CombiningCyclesCase2[[i]]] + 1, n]] -> 
   Range[Max[CombiningCyclesCase2[[i]]] + 1, n]], {i, 
  Length[CombiningCyclesCase2]}]
```

However, I get the error `Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot be used as a part specification. >>`. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this problem or if there is an easier way to do this?

Comment: Are you the same as [cesar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/41295/cesar)? If so, you can talk to the moderators to get your two accounts merged.

Answer (score 8):

One solution:

```
MapIndexed[If[# == 0, Last[#2], #] &, CombiningCyclesCase2, {2}]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = ReplacePart[#, # -> Last @# & /@ Position[#, 0]]&;

f @ CombiningCyclesCase2
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

If your lists are large (and rectangular as your example), this s/b considerably faster than existing answers:

```
fix=With[{d=Dimensions@#},#+BitXor[1,Unitize@#]*ConstantArray[Range@d[[2]],d[[1]]]]&;
```

or simpler and similar speed:

```
fix2=With[{rx = Range@Length@#[[1]]}, (# + BitXor[1, Unitize[#]]*rx) & /@ #] &;
```

Comment: I'm so sorry.Seemed a bit repetitive to your answer.If necessary,I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
fun:=(1-Unitize[#])*Range[Length@#]+#&
```

## Usage

```
fun/@CombiningCyclesCase2
```

> {{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,4,3,5},{1,2,4,5,3},{3,2,1,4,5},{3,2,1,5,4},{3,2,4,1,5},{3,4,1,2,5},{3,2,4,5,1},{3,5,4,1,2}}

Answer (score 1):

```
foo[x_] := ReplacePart[i_ :> If[x[[i]] == 0, i, x[[i]]]] @ x

foo /@ CombiningCyclesCase2
```

{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 4, 3, 5}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 3}, {3, 2, 1, 4,
5}, {3, 2, 1, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 4, 1, 5}, {3, 4, 1, 2, 5}, {3, 2, 4, 5,
1}, {3, 5, 4, 1, 2}}

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this using `Delete`, `Partition` and `Riffle`:

```
f[l_] := Map[Apply[Join, #] &,
    Partition[
            Riffle[Function[Delete[#, Position[#, 0]]][l],
                Map[Function @ Complement[Range @ Last @ Dimensions @ #, #], l]
            ],
            {2}
        ]
   ];
```

Test:

```
f@CombiningCyclesCase2

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 4, 3, 5}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 3}, {3, 2, 1, 4, 5}, 
{3, 2, 1, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 4, 1, 5}, {3, 4, 1, 2, 5}, {3, 2, 4, 5, 1}, {3, 5, 4, 1, 2}}*)
```

Comment: You can think about removing the `MatrixQ` restriction.

Answer (score 0):

`MapIndexed` was designed to handle such problems. However, in the interest of computational diversity, let's use `MapThread` with `PositionIndex`. I have added a slightly longer sublist for testing and taken some liberty with output styles.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
CombiningCyclesCase2 = {{1, 2, 3, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 4, 3, 0}, {1, 2, 4, 5,
    3}, {3, 2, 1, 4, 0}, {3, 2, 1, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 4, 1, 5}, {3, 4, 1, 
   2, 5}, {0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 11}, {3, 2, 4, 5, 1}, {3, 5, 4, 1, 
   2}};

reps = PositionIndex[#][0] & /@ 
   CombiningCyclesCase2 /. {Missing[__] :> {}, 
   a_Integer :> a -> Style[a, Red]} 

MapThread[ReplacePart[#1, #2] &,  {CombiningCyclesCase2, reps}]
```

[image]